# graphql mergeSchemas from GraphQLObjectType schemas

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, graphql-tools

I'm new to graphql so i'm facing some problems.
Server based on nodeJS with express package. I'm writing my schemas for  Apollo Graphql in GraphQLObjectType notation.
When i want to merge two schemas in one i use mergeSchemas method from graphql-tools npm package and got some errors with merging. Can anyone point me what i'm doing incorrect?

```
const { mergeSchemas } = require('graphql-tools');
const { GraphQLSchema } = require('graphql');

const queryType = require('./queryType');
const eventMutations = require('./eventMutations');
const userMutations = require('./userMutations');

const mutationType = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [eventMutations, userMutations],
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: queryType,
  mutation: mutationType,
});
```

each of eventMutations, userMutations is GraphQLObjectType

The error is:

```
Invalid schema passed
```

at

```
mergeSchemas({...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I wanted to merge GraphQLObjectType but not really GraphQLSchema.
So the solution was to create GraphQLSchema for user and event and then perfectly merge them together.